# How to see a "hidden" follower on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr, followers

I just wanted to know how to see all people who are following me on Tumblr.

The easiest way for you to understand what I mean is by an example so let's say on my dashboard, where it indicates the amount of followers I have—it says "10." So I've technically got 10 followers, but when I click on "followers" I see & count only 9. How can I know who that tenth follower is?

Extra info:
This isn't on my main Tumblr but on an other blog of mine. I am following myself and I am shown on the list, but not the mysterious other. It even says, as a caption, and continuing the example of before, "10 people follow this blog" but only 9 are shown.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with full list of your other blog followers? Just don't forget to substitute proper part of the URL to the right with the name of that blog.

```
http://www.tumblr.com/blog/PUT-NAME-OF-BLOG-HERE/followers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your emails, you have an email every time someone follows you. Just work back on that list and check if they are a follower on the `https://www.tumblr.com/blog/YOURBLOG/followers` by using their blog name in the search.